# How do i know if my sync is in fast mode?

Tags: go-ethereum, windows, fast-sync

I entered "geth" command from my powerShell comandline. There was no ChainData directory.
I am running Windows 10 64 bit. I downloaded Geth v1.8.3 for windows 64 bit
The machine has 250 GB SSD. The internet connection is 3 Mbps. No other process is running.

its 3 days now, about 4300 files downloaded in my ChainData folder and sync is still running.

How do i know if it is running in fast mode?
How long is it going to still take? In other words, how many more nodes it still has to download, like "downloading 4300 out of 10000"?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach to your node with

```
$ geth attach
```

If that does not work you can specify the open port (if you started geth with `--rpc`)

```
$ geth attach http://localhost:8545
```

Or attach to the ipc

```
$ geth attach /path/to/geth.ipc
```

And in the console run

```
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 5143627,
  highestBlock: 5171324,
  knownStates: 91997982,
  pulledStates: 91997982,
  startingBlock: 5143610
}
```

Comment: I opened a new console and ran "geth attach http://localhost:8545". It gave following error --
Fatal: Failed to start the JavaScript console: api modules: Post http://localhost:8545: dial tcp [::1]:8545: connectex:
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: @Andy I've added a few more options how to connect to your node. Tell me if those work